# Get RSelenium to print URL's that it's finished scraping

Tags: r, for-loop, rselenium

I'm running a loop to scrape a massive amount of data using RSelenium. If the loop breaks, I'd like to see the element and URL where RSelenium left off at.

Is there a way to print out the element the link is in and the url as each page is completed?

Using the below prints `[[1]] [1] ""` and that's it.

```
# check completed links
complete <- rd$findElement(using = "tag name", "a")
for(url in length(complete)){
     done <- complete[[url]]
     print(done$getElementText())
 }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense to me.  Where do you fetch a particular URL?  In any case, the answer is to print the URL you are trying to fetch, then print "done\n" when you're done with it.

Comment: I considered adding that to this post, but it would've made it way too long. How would you get it to print the url and done when it's finished?

Comment: `print(url); .. get it ...; print("done")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCurrentUrl()` instead of `getElementText()`:

```r
library(RSelenium)

driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]

remote_driver$navigate("https://www.r-project.org/")
remote_driver$getCurrentUrl()
```

```r
[[1]]
[1] "https://www.r-project.org/"
```